# How to force discarding ALL my unstaged changes in Git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

How to remove the items under "Changes not staged for commit:". I found many other tickets in this regards, but none actually worked with me.

**What happened ?**

I checked out the development branch. But after i edited some local files, these files got stuck in the Unstaged list. Can't `stash`, `clean`, `rm` or even `reset --hard` them at all. The problem happened when i was trying to remove my local changes by checking out origin/mybranch then trying to reset from there.

Some how i have now an outdated branch. Every time i do :

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/mybranch
```

the unstaged changes STILL there.

```
modified : *.xlsx
```

Ho can i force removal of these local changes. It seems the only solution is to clone a clean revision again, but i'm trying to fix it first.

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: @akuhn modified : *

modified : *

modified : *

The locally modified files all still listed every time i hit :
git status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this problem happened only with *.xlsx files because every time it's opened by Excel it create a hidden file $*.xlsx. Apparently the same issue with other office document files. If i added the changes through :

```
git add .
```

It will blindly add even the hidden file $*.xlsx . So after i closed the file, automatically it was removed from the system but not from git because it was added already, git still sees it and can't ignore it or even remove because it was untracked.

What worked for me that i opened the excel file, add, then commit without issues. After that i can remove as any other file.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
git checkout .
```

The '.' is used to indicate that you want to replace ALL the files with the version present in origin.

Comment: I tried that already in mybranch and in the origin. Didn't work. git keeps telling me that i'm already up-to-date with the origin/mybranch but still lists the unstaged changes. 

I tried : git checkout -- .

Answer (score 0):

The changes not staged can be "removed" using the following command:

```
git checkout -- <filename>
```

Or, if you want to remove all the changes, you can use `.`

```
git checkout -- .
```

This should be sufficient to remove items under "Changes not staged for commit".

Comment: it doesn't remove the unstaged changes or have any effect in this case i don't know why. What i don't understand that git when i reset the brahc --hard to match the latest fetch origin; it tells me that mybranch is up-to-date with origin/mybranch .. but still lists the unstaged changes and when i do git add . --dry-run ... i see all of these changes still there and ready to be staged and committed.

Answer (score 0):

If these files you've changed are within a tracked directory and you are looking to permanently exclude them from the project, you would need to add them to your repository's .gitignore file.